# tcolorbox manual tip box, how to clone?

Tags: tcolorbox

I would like to clone this box used on the `tcolorbox` manual, but I couldn't find the configuration in the manual.

[image: Tcolorbox tip]

Can you help me?

Comment: It's in the documentation source only. Look for `marker` -- I explicitly asked the package author however, for permission to use the code!

Comment: You're more likely to get a helpful answer by supplying some initial code-frame and showing the work you already put into it.

Answer (score 20):

The code box is called `marker` and can be found in [`tcolorbox.doc.s_main.sty`](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/blob/master/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.doc.s_main.sty), i.e. the documentation source of `tcolorbox` manual.

The `marker` environment is made with `\newtcolorbox` and has an optional argument to allow further customization.

The `corner` is made with some underlay using `TikZ`.

Side note: I am using the `marker` environment in the documentation of  personal packages after I have asked Thomas F. Sturm for permission. I think this will be granted to everyone given that there is some remark about Thomas' contribution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{marker}[1][]{enhanced,
  before skip=2mm,after skip=3mm,
  boxrule=0.4pt,left=5mm,right=2mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,
  colback=yellow!50,
  colframe=yellow!20!black,
  sharp corners,rounded corners=southeast,arc is angular,arc=3mm,
  underlay={%
    \path[fill=tcbcolback!80!black] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);
    \path[draw=tcbcolframe,shorten <=-0.05mm,shorten >=-0.05mm] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);
    \path[fill=yellow!50!black,draw=none] (interior.south west) rectangle node[white]{\Huge\bfseries !} ([xshift=4mm]interior.north west);
    },
  drop fuzzy shadow,#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{marker}
Foo
\end{marker}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For readers in 2021 or later: 1) Please go to [the source of `tcolorbox.doc.s_main.sty`](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/blob/master/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.doc.s_main.sty) and search for `marker` to get the latest definition. 2) In the doc for `tcolorbox` v4.50, the first two options `before skip=2mm,after skip=3mm` has been replaced with `before skip balanced=2mm,after skip balanced=3mm`, which were introduced in v4.40.  3) Also for v4.50, my test shows the minimal dependence is `\tcbuselibrary{skins}`.

Comment: @galen see my previous comment.