# Note frame with tcolorbox package

Tags: tcolorbox

How to create frames as shown below with `tcolorbox` package. Although I did learn about it but did not know how to create the begging you help me thanks!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is this from some package's documentation? Then you'll probably find the sources on CTAN.

Comment: See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307436/121799).

Comment: Well the framework is in the documentation of the tcolorbox package but there are no instructions for creating it. Please help me create such a frame