# How to create an article summary template?

Tags: tikz-styles, fancybox

I would like to create a box so that the summary is inside, the detail of the box is that it has a detail in the lower right corner.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Have your tried `\begin{abstract}....\end{abstract}`? If this doesn't help then please edit your question to give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) showing what you have tired because, at a minimum, it will help to know what document class you are using. A MWE should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Please have a look at section 4.8 Corners of the tcolorbox manual.

Comment: I want that detail from the bottom right corner, that cut into a box.

Comment: I want that detail from the bottom right corner, that cut into a box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I focus here on the box, which I almost entirely stole from [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307436/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{WeMissChristian}[1][]{enhanced,
  before skip=2mm,after skip=3mm,
  boxrule=0.4pt,left=5mm,right=2mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,
  colback=yellow!50,
  colframe=yellow!20!black,
  sharp corners,rounded corners=southeast,arc is angular,arc=3mm,
 #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{WeMissChristian}
\subsubsection*{Abstract}
\lipsum[1]

\paragraph{key words:} hibernation, black forest, ducks
\end{WeMissChristian}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Those of you who think an abstract needs to be typeset in a dedicated environment: please don't jump at me, I'm just a marmot. ;-)

Comment: That's right!!! Thank you very much "marmot".

Comment: How to create this "\newtcolorbox ..." in an .sty file and use it in .tex file. I want to leave the .tex file clean.