# How to create tcolorbox this like?

Tags: tcolorbox

[image]
I cannot create the tcolorbox like above. Thanks to everyone for help

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE. In the form of an MWE, could you show us what you have tried so-far?

Comment: Possible duplicate to [tcolorbox manual tip box, how to clone?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/307432/134144)