# Box design with tikz or tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, box

[image][image]
I found this box template in the tcolor box document, but didn't know the design.  Can you share the sample with me?  or maybe help me design it myself.  thanks

Comment: Welcome! See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307436.

Comment: Ohh, thank you very much bro 